# How to find the inverse of this exponential function?

Tags: functions, inverse

Here is the function... It is $y=e^{x-3}+5$, I have no clue how to find the inverse of it. I graphed the function but now it says find the inverse and graph it. I do not know how to graph it.

Comment: Presumably, you want parentheses around $x-3$?

Comment: $y=e^{x-3}+5\iff y-5=e^{x-3}\iff \log(y-5)=x-3\iff \log(y-5)+3=x$

Comment: Thank you for editing it Thomas Andrews, I didn't know how to write it that way

Comment: Did you copy my answer, @PeterTamaroff? :)P

Answer (score 1):

$$y=e^{x-3}+5\iff e^{x-3}=y-5\iff x-3=\log(y-5)\iff x=\log(y-5)+3$$

thus the inverse is $\,g(x)=\log(x-5)+3\,$

Comment: Nop, I just saw it when you wrote $\,y=e^x-3+5\,$ and, at that moment, the OP already was $\,e^{x-3}+5\,$...reading the first comment, it's obvious the OP forgot parentheses around the exponent...:)

Comment: De México - Israel. Saludos.

Comment: BALEETED. ${}{}$

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07h0ksKx5sM)

Comment: Debe de ser la famosa barrera generacional: no entiendo nada.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the inverse

(1) Draw the original curve.

(2) Draw the line $y=x$.

(3) **Reflect** the original curve in the double-sided mirror $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Solve the equation $y = e^{x-3} + 5$ for $x$.